# SQL_Alchemy reconstructs objects

Tags: sqlalchemy

I was recently bitten by the behavior of SQL_Alchemy when it reconstructs objects.

Specially, I defined a class that was mapped onto a table. Objects of this class maintained state information that was not stored in the database. My program was breaking because periodically SQL_Alchemy would reconstruct the object, at which point the state information was lost. I know that SA was reconstructing the objects because I created a method and decorated it with @orm.reconstructor, so I could see when the objects were getting rebuilt.

My questions are:

1) Is SQL_Alchemy's behavior about object reconstruction documented and if so where?

2) Is there a way to control this (i.e. turn it off?)

3) What are appropriate recipes for building an object model that allows an object maintained by SQL Alchemy to maintain state information that is not reflected in the actual database?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're talking about, perhaps you could elaborate with some minimal code samples, and some data for actual vs. expected behaviour.

One wild guess: If you want to maintain the changed state of an object during subsequent queries, which could also update that state, try detaching this object from the session.